# How to append the checked checkbox to the top of the list in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some list of HTML check box in the table and its related data. In the list if I have selected a check box that will move to the top of the list.
Below is my code it works in `<div>` but not in the `<table>`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.t1 .group-title').each(function() {
    $if(this.checked) {
      $item.insertBefore($('.t1 .group-title').first())
    } else {
      $item.appendTo($item.data('group'))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1">
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2">
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Title 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk3">
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Title 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" name="chk4">
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Title 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk5" name="chk5">
      </td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Title 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$('table').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var row = $this.closest('tr');
  if ($this.prop('checked')) { // move to top
    row.insertBefore(row.parent().find('tr:first-child'))
      .find('label').html('move to bottom');
  } else { // move to bottom
    row.insertAfter(row.parent().find('tr:last-child'))
      .find('label').html('move to top');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should bind the `change` event to checkbox element. Then based of `checked` state `prepend()`/`append()` parent `tr` element.

```
$('#t1 :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var tbody = $('#t1 tbody')
    if (this.checked) {
        tbody.prepend(tr)
    } else {
        tbody.append(tr)
    }
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#t1 :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var tbody = $('#t1 tbody')
    if (this.checked) {
      tbody.prepend(tr)
    } else {
      tbody.append(tr)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1">
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2">
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Title 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk3">
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Title 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" name="chk4">
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Title 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk5" name="chk5">
      </td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Title 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to handle the event on change for the checkboxes, and then if the checkbox is checked you should prepend the tr parent to the tbody of your table.

```
$("#t1 input:checkbox").on("change",function(){
  if(this.checked){
    $("#t1 tbody").prepend($(this).parents("tr"))
  }else{
    $("#t1 tbody").append($(this).parents("tr"))
  }
})
```

Here is a fiddle with your example working 
https://jsfiddle.net/kLhxq3Lj/